# Python Pandas csv_read generates HTTPError

Tags: python, pandas

This is probably a newbie question but I can't get my head around it and need help to understand what is happening. I want to retrieve data from text (.txt) files from a URL and put the data into a `Pandas` dataframe for further manipulation. Since `csv_read` allows me to retrieve data from a URL, that was my default choice but for some reason I get a HTTPError 400 (Bad Request) exception. So I tried retrieving the same file from the same URL using the `Request` module which works fine. The bizarre and inexplicable (to me) part is that the `csv_read` command will execute without exception as long as the `request` retrieval precedes it. I fail to understand why the `csv_read` command throws an exception when executed alone but the same piece of code executes just fine without any exception if I have executed a completely independent code snippet using another module just before it.

I could obviously retrieve the files using `request` and then pass the data into a `pandas` dataframe, but I am not happy circumventing the issue without understanding why. I have included the code below with some comments to illustrate the problem/question. I am on macOS.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

## This is the file I want to retrieve
link = 'https://seb.se/pow/fmk/2100/fonder_2019-10-17.TXT'

## 1. Retrieves the file/data via requests. Works fine.
f = requests.get(link)
print(f.text)

## 2. Retrieves the file via csv_read. This part will execute fine if the first segment runs before it, but if I comment out the two lines under 1 this code will throw a HTTPError 400 (Bad Request.
c = pd.read_csv(link, encoding='iso-8859-1', header=None, sep=';', names=["Date","Fund","NAV","ID"])
print(c.head())
```

The exception traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Documents/seb_fonder_filer.py", line 13, in getFile
    c = pd.read_csv(link, header=None, sep=';', encoding='ISO-8859-1', names=["Date","Fund","NAV","ID"])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 685, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 439, in _read
    fp_or_buf, _, compression, should_close = get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 196, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    req = urlopen(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Comment: Pretty weird it works fine for me... I'm using `pandas==0.24.0` and `requests==2.22.0`

Comment: Are you sure it's panda's csv returning the http400 error?

Comment: I am on `pandas==0.25.3` and `requests==2.22.0` plus python 3.8. @Jules did you try commenting out the `requests` retrieval too?

Comment: It works for me calling it directly with no other imports: `pd.read_csv('https://seb.se/pow/fmk/2100/fonder_2019-10-17.TXT', encoding='iso-8859-1', header=None, sep=';', names=["Date","Fund","NAV","ID"]).head()` returns a dataframe. You might have an issue with urllib which pandas uses as a backend for web requests. Can you [edit] to include the full error traceback?

Comment: yes... Just running this: `pd.read_csv('https://seb.se/pow/fmk/2100/fonder_2019-10-17.TXT', encoding='iso-8859-1', header=None, sep=';', names=["Date","Fund","NAV","ID"])` works

Comment: @G.Anderson added traceback. Yes it is a urllib exception as it is the backend module for pandas for this function

Comment: perhaps escaping the URL...?
`import urllib
 link = urllib.quote('https://seb.se/pow/fmk/2100/fonder_2019-10-17.TXT')`

Comment: @ElegantCode Thanks, tried that to no avail. It obfuscates the colon and I end up getting a FileNotFound error.